# Are questions about the conduct of Christian Studies at an academic level on topic here?

Tags: discussion, scope

The question that prompted this query:

[Is there funding to Present at the SBL (Society of Biblical Literature) both/either the international or national one?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/47960/is-there-funding-to-present-at-the-sbl-society-of-biblical-literature-both-eit)

Is such a question on-topic or off-topic?

If off-topic, we already have ones like:

[What is the difference between a Bible College and a Seminary?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/9248/what-is-the-difference-between-a-bible-college-and-a-seminary?s=1|0.9288)

and

[Who pays for Protestant seminary education for aspiring ministers?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/19430/who-pays-for-protestant-seminary-education-for-aspiring-ministers)

These have remained open - are there any issues with them?

Assuming a general answer of yes to the title question, there will obviously be some overlap with the coverage of Christianity.SE and academia.SE; Given that, what are some appropriate guidelines for which would be the more appropriate place for such questions?

Comment: Questions about the "business of Christianity". I think they should be on topic. They're to practical to not be.

Answer (score 4):

The linked question that prompted this query does not fit any of the topics allowed here. It isn't a question about Christianity at all. An answer to this question would not provide any significant information about the beliefs and practices of any Christian group or denomination.

Rather than being a question about Christianity, it's someone looking for sources of funding. That's not what this site is for—even if the funding is sought for Christianity-related research and writing.

The other two linked questions seem a bit marginal, but at least they're about the practices of particular groups of Christians, and the related terminology, which makes them on-topic for this site. Those two questions are seeking information about Christian practices. The purpose of the first question is to seek funding.

Answer (score 0):

I think all these questions are on-topic, though they may not all be questions we're really equipped to answer. But that's not a problem, we have lots of other unanswered or poorly answered questions.

Comment: I agree, except I think the one that got closed is too localized.